# Same \chapterformat for \chapter and \chapter* without titlesec

Tags: sectioning, chapters, koma-script

I've done some styling for my chapter titles, based upon *tikz* and the *titlesec* package.

Unfortunately, the KOMA-Script packages gives me numerous warnings about *titlesec*. In order to get rid of the titlesec-package, I've tried to accomplish the same chapter style with the build-in `\chapterformat` of KOMA-Script. This works quite well, until I noticed that the `\chapter*`-like headings (e.g. TOC and so on) were not affected.

After doing some research, I've found the - trivial - reason for this behaviour. `\chapterformat` affects only the number part of the title. All the `\chapter*` have no chapter number, so `\chapterformat` does not work.

### The Question

Is it possible to format both \chapter and \chapter* with pure KOMA-Script, or does this require *titlesec* or a similar package?

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand{\chapterformat}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \draw[fill=gray,draw=none] (0,0) rectangle (1cm,1cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \thechapter
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{The Chapter}
\blindtext
\chapter*{The Chapter without number}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

### compiled MWE

### [image: MWE, compiled with pdflatex/miktex 2.9/KOMAScript 3.18]

### Just for info

This is maybe not really part of the question, however that's the current `\chapter` style in my document. `\chapter*` should have the same position and background, without the orange bar. The one above is only a MWE for demo purposes.

[image: This is the styled chapter]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's (well-known) that one should not use `KOMA` and `titlesec` together. Either `KOMA`  **xor** `titlesec`, then use a different class, `report`, for example.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Does this mean, that there is no way to have a styled `\chapter*` in `KOMA`? By the way, what exactly is the reason for this advice? I've already used them both together and I've never experienced any problems, only the warnings from `KOMA`. Is this some kind of a 'It could crash with the next version'-problem?

Comment: Well, as you wrote: `It could crash with the next version`. KOMA and `titlesec` both do 'strange' things to the sectioning commands and their headings and both do it differently, as far as I know. I think, many of the stuff done with `titlesec` can be done with KOMA macros too, but I have to admit, that I am no fan of neither KOMA nor `titlesec`, so others should provide real answers. This is of course only a comment

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since KOMA-Script version 3.19 the command `\chapterlinesformat` can be redefined to change the layout of chapter titles which have no prefix line. Now it is possible to position the chapter title in a graý box on top of the page without using `scrlayer-scrpage`. And chapter titles with more than one line are possible.

```latex
\documentclass[twoside,open=any]{scrreprt}[2015/10/03]
%\providecommand*\Ifstr{\ifstr}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif
%\providecommand*\Ifthispageodd{\ifthispageodd}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=1sp minus 1sp,
  afterskip=4\baselineskip plus .2\baselineskip minus .2\baselineskip,
  font=\Huge\scshape\color{white}
]{chapter}

\renewcommand\chapterformat{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\thechapter\enskip
    \textcolor{orange}{\smash{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{2.5pt}{\baselineskip}}}%
}}

\newlength\chapterleftmargin
\newcommand\chaptervmargin{1.5em}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \vspace*{\dimexpr-1in-\headsep-\headheight-\topmargin-1ex}%
  \Ifthispageodd
    {\setlength\chapterleftmargin{\dimexpr1in+\hoffset+\oddsidemargin\relax}}
    {\setlength\chapterleftmargin{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\textwidth-1in-\hoffset-\oddsidemargin\relax}}
    \hspace*{-\chapterleftmargin}%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{%
      \colorbox{gray}{%
        \parbox[t][\dimexpr\totalheight+\chaptervmargin*2\relax][c]{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{%
          \makebox[\dimexpr\chapterleftmargin-\fboxsep\relax][r]{#2}%
          \Ifstr{#2}{}
            {\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\raggedchapter#3}}
            {\enskip\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-.5em\relax}{\raggedchapter#3}}%
        }%
      }%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{The chapter}
\KOMAScriptVersion

\Blindtext
\chapter*{The Chapter without number}
\blindtext
\chapter{A long long long long chapter title with more than one line}
\blindtext
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Run twice (because of `\Ifthispageodd`) to get

[image]